# What does mean, lines.next.toInt in Java

Tags: java, scala

What does mean this line in java:

```
m = lines.next.toInt
```

Thanks.

Comment: is Scala code. Just I need to know how I can interpretate in Java.

Comment: it's not incomplete. is Scala!

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question to make more clear, what you are intending to want to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this done in java using any reader. e.g- BufferedReader, FileReader anything like this.

```
public class InJava
{
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//
//in main()
public static void main(String [] args)
{
   Object obj= br.readLine();
}
}
```

If you are using a list use Iterator.

```
public class InJava
{
List<double> lst= new ArrayList<double>();
//fill the list.
Iterator it= lst.iterator();
//in main()
while(it.hasNext())
{
Object obj= it.next();
//Continue
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`lines` is perhaps an iterable collection of `Double` objects. The code that you've posted accesses the next element in sequence and converts it to an integer.

If you can post the surrounding code as well, we could get more context on the same.

Comment: I guess `lines` is result of `io.Source.fromFile(...).getLines()`. So it's an `Iterator[String]`, not `Iterator[Double]`.

Comment: You've tagged scala as well in the question right? Parentheses for function invocation are optional in scala. A Java compiler would obviously flag these as errors.

Comment: @user3126974 You may accomplish similiar functionality with [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Thanks @PeterMmm I was thinking that it would be the same than Scanner.